# Drawing dashed multicolumn table

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I want to draw a multicolumn table, such that for every row, the second and third columns are divided into two parts, and there is a dashed line separating the two parts. Currently, I have something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{paper}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|*{7}{c|}}
\hline
\multirowcell{2}{Function} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Input(s)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Output(s)} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Operations} \\
\cdashline{2-3} \cline{4-7}
& Type(s) & Type(s) & M & S & a & I \\
\hline
$\mathtt{j\_inv}$ & $(A, C)$ \\ $K \times K$ & $j(E)$ \\ $K$ & 3 & 4 & 8 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Summary of functions}
\label{tab:functions}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The point is that the table header is exactly as I want, but then in the second row when I start to actually write the values, I do not know how to make the second and third column divided into two parts like their header, and divided by a dashed line. Simply, I put the newline symbol between the two parts, but it does not give the desired effect of course. Any ideas how to achieve what I want?

Comment: Could you please post a code that does not throw errors?

Comment: @marmot This code is not supposed to throw error, I believe. It compiles successfully, but the end result is not what I desire. The header is all fine, take the second row which includes values, for the second column I have written `$(A, C)$ \\ $K`, how this should be displayed is that ` $(A, C)$` should be at the top, then a dashed line comes and then `$K$` underneath the dashed line. Similar idea for the third column too. I achieve that for the headers, but don't know how to achieve that for the actual values.

Comment: Well it does not compile on my TeXLive 2017 distribution with either pdflatex, xelatex or lualatex.

Comment: @marmot How about now? I believe `arydshln` needs to be loaded last.

Comment: Yes, now it compiles. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely I am missing something. You have already found out in the header how to split a cell. Why can't you just repeat it?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{paper}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|*{7}{c|}}
\hline
\multirowcell{2}{Function} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Input(s)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Output(s)} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Operations} \\
\cdashline{2-3} \cline{4-7}
& Type(s) & Type(s) & M & S & a & I \\
\hline
\multirowcell{2}{$\mathtt{j\_inv}$} & $(A, C)$ &
$K \times K$ & $j(E)$ & & &\\ 
\cdashline{2-3} \cline{4-7}
& $K$ & 3 & 4 & 8 & 1 &\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Summary of functions}
\label{tab:functions}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If this is not the output you want, you may benefit from posting an annotated table in which you explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, this is the output I want, I was trying to use `\multicolumn` again in the second row. That was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

In `{NiceTabular}`, you merge cells both horizontally and vertically with the command `\Block`. For the rows, you give the number of *logical* rows (and not the number of physical lines as with `\multicolumn`).

With the key `hvlines`, all the rules are drawn, excepted in the blocks (constructed by `\Block`).

Since `nicematrix` creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows ans columns of the array, it's possible to use Tikz to draw whatever (dashed) rule you want after the construction of the array.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{paper}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccccc}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=3pt]
\Block{2-1}{Function} & \Block{2-1}{} Input(s) & \Block{2-1}{} Output(s) & Operations \\
& Type(s) & Type(s) & M & S & a & I \\
\Block{2-1}{$\mathtt{j\_inv}$} & \Block{2-1}{} $(A, C)$ & \Block{2-1}{} $K \times K$ & $j(E)$ \\
& $K$ & 3 & 4 & 8 & 1 \\ 
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw [dashed] (2-|2) -- (2-|4)   (4-|2) -- (4-|4) ;
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Summary of functions}
\label{tab:functions}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]